# how to filter a complex object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object like the following.

```
example:[
{
    "Id":"100",
    "value":"Egor1",
    "children":{
        "pilot":[
            {
                "Properties":{
                    "Id":123,
                    "History":[
                        20191101,
                        20191112,
                        20191103
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "Id":"200",
    "value":"Egor2",
    "children":{
        "pilot":[
            {
                "Properties":{
                    "Id":234,
                    "History":[
                        20191001,
                        20191012,
                        20191003,
                        20190902
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "Id":"300",
    "value":"Egor3",
    "children":{
        "pilot":[
            {
                "Properties":{
                    "Id":456,
                    "History":[
                        20190901,
                        20190912,
                        20190903,
                        20191101
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

]

I have an input  20191101. Sometimes input can be 20191101,20191001. I need to filter the example if

```
children.pilot.properties.history[0]=== 20191101.
```

I tried the following:

```
const result = example.filter( task => task.children.pilot.properties.history.includes(getPbfValueByFilter(task.childen, input))
  );
```

getPbfValueByFilter method :

```
const getPbfValueByFilter = (allChilden, input) => {
const { features } = allChilden.pilot;
const test = input.toString().split(',');

if (isUndefined(features) || isEmpty(features)
|| isUndefined(features.properties.History)) {
return [];
}
 test.map((each) => {
 if (each === features.properties.History[0]) {
 console.log("here" + features.properties.History[0])
 return allChilden;
}

});
};
```

expected output :

```
[
{
    "Id": "100",
    "value": "Egor1",
    "children": {
        "pilot": [
            {
                "Properties": {
                    "Id": 123,
                    "History": [
                        20191101,
                        20191112,
                        20191103
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
]
```

I am getting the console part. But it is unable to fetch the result. I assume that 'includes' is not working as expected. What went wrong. Please advice.
TIA.

Comment: `pilot` is an array not an object and javascript object property names are case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `some` with `filter`. Let me know if this is what you are looking for:

```js
var input=[20191101];
var example=[{ "Id":"100", "value":"Egor1", "children":{ "pilot":[ { "Properties":{ "Id":123, "History":[ 20191101, 20191112, 20191103 ] } } ] }},{ "Id":"200", "value":"Egor2", "children":{ "pilot":[ { "Properties":{ "Id":234, "History":[ 20191001, 20191012, 20191003, 20190902 ] } } ] }},{ "Id":"300", "value":"Egor3", "children":{ "pilot":[ { "Properties":{ "Id":456, "History":[ 20190901, 20190912, 20190903, 20191101 ] } } ] }}];

var result = example.filter(k=>k.children.pilot.some(d=>d.Properties.History.some(p=>input.includes(p))));

var result2 = example.filter(k=>k.children.pilot.some(d=>input.includes(d.Properties.History[0])));


console.log(result2);
//console.log(result);
```

Comment: No, I need to filter the example based on the following condition (if the first element of  History matches with input. Here expected task would be)                                                          
      children.pilot.properties.history[0]=== 20191101.                                                                 expected result would be  the History which contains the input as first element

Comment: @treena, you need filtering on only the first object of the array. Can you edit your question and provide expected output?

Comment: @treena Updated my answer, I have put `input` as an array (you mentioned it could be multiple). Have a look and let me know.

Answer (score -1):

According to the example object pilot is an array so the filter should be something like this:

```js
const result = example.filter((task) =>
  task.children.pilot[0].properties.history.includes(
    getPbfValueByFilter(task.children, input)
  )
);
```

Comment: You have typos in some of the property names

Comment: @charlietfl I just copied same code as it is in the question, I dont know if the typo is the example object or the filter function

Comment: Well when OP provides sample data you need to assume that it is correct

Comment: But he also provided the code of the filter function and that was the base for my answer, take a look at the question ;)

Comment: Sure but you are continuing the same mistake OP made

Comment: The thing is that for me the error is in the object not in the filter function,  camelcase is the standard, no?